# How can I concatenate different fields type in a String field

Tags: string, casting

I have to add some fields values in a string. The fields are Id, date, string and integer. The point is I can do this in that way:

```
String s;
s= record.Id + record.Name + record.Date__c  + record.Code__c;
```

I've tested that and it's working but when I try to change the order of the fields I get this error "Arithmetic expressions must use numeric arguments".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure there's way the compiler thinks you're trying to do math (e.g. two numbers next to each other). A simple fix is to place an empty string between each value (or whatever you want to use for separation between values):

```
String s = record.Id + '' + record.Name + '' + record.Date__c + '' + record.Code__c;
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks